# CSS: Hide an element when another element is hidden

Tags: css, hide, element

I have the following questions:

I already have a code that hides *class element 1* when it has a specific value (which is not the same on all sites).

Now I also want to hide *class element 2* ONLY IF *class element 1* is already hidden.

Do you guys have any idea on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem with this question is that the code is hidden for us. Please add a relevant code snippet so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to add a class that will hide the element it self and the next one.
when you add "hideElement1" class to parent you hide element1 and element2 and so on,
i recommend this solution only if you have small amount of elements otherwise you should use JavaScript.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="element1">element1</div>
    <div class="element2">element2</div>
    <div class="element3">element3</div>
    <div class="element4">element4</div>
</div>

<label for="tbx">insert number</label>
<input type="number" id="tbx" name="tbx" value="" />
<input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="click to hide" />

<style>
    .parent.hideElement1 .element1, .parent.hideElement1 .element2 {
        display: none;
    }

    .parent.hideElement2 .element2, .parent.hideElement2 .element3 {
        display: none;
    }

    .parent.hideElement3 .element3, .parent.hideElement3 .element4 {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script>

    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    var tbx = document.getElementById('tbx');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        hideElementbyIndex(tbx.value);
    });

    function hideElementbyIndex(elementIndex) {
        var elementClassNamePrefix = 'element';

        var elementsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName(elementClassNamePrefix + elementIndex);
        hideAll(elementsToHide);
        elementIndex++;
        var nextElementsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName(elementClassNamePrefix + elementIndex);
        hideAll(nextElementsToHide);
    }

    function hideAll(elements) {
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[0].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }


</script>
```

Comment: but this means that it will always hide my parent element, isn't it? I only want to hide the second element if the first one is hidden which is not always the case

Comment: No!
 .parent.hideElement3 .element3 {display:none;}
means hide all element with class "element3"  that are inside an element that has both "parent" and "hideElement3" classes
for more information about css selectors visit [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and also use 
[CSS Selector Tester](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have a css style that says `display: none` and then use `element.classList.add('cssclass')` or `remove` or `toggle`.

Toggle is the best because if it sees the class is in, it will remove or add respectively.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to hide an element and the element next to it you should use "+" selector.

```
.hiderClass,
.hiderClass + .element {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: how would you do this on this line of code? 

.wc_review_badge_inner[data-count="0"]{display:none !important;} (this is the element that hides if the value is 0)

.wc_review_section (this is the element that should be hidden when the first one is hidden, but only then)

Comment: Try this:

.wc_review_badge_inner[data-count="0"],
.wc_review_badge_inner[data-count="0"] + .wc_review_section {
    display:none !important;
}

and i got a demo for you. Here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/4zL7dsah/